# Localized NOSQL objects with user like data

Tags: firebase, localization, firebase-realtime-database, denormalization

I am newer to the nosql world and am having a hard time with a certain aspect of denormalization and how my database should be architected. I will be using Firebase, but I believe this problem extends to denormalization in general.

The issue that I have is how to mark user "likes" against a piece of data when that data (lets call it "strings") is localized in many languages. Ideally I would do something like:

```
{
  en: {
    strings: {
      0: "String 0 in English",
      1: "String 1 in English",
      ...
    }
  },
  es: {
    strings: {
      0: "String 0 in Spanish",
      1: "String 1 in Spanish",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

This way I could access the desired text in the desired language with just the query path. Easy - Except for liking. Being a global and localized set of data, if a Spanish user likes "string[0]", it should be a like against "string[0]" for all languages. I don't even know where to store "likeCount" in a setup like this.

Another approach I thought of was having the localized strings together like:

```
{
  strings: {
    0: {
      likeCount: 110,
      string: {
        en: "String 0 in English",
        es: "String 0 in Spanish"
      }
    },
    1: {
      likeCount: 13,
      string: {
        en: "String 0 in English",
        es: "String 1 in Spanish"
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is more obvious here that the "likeCount" can be attached directly to the object in this case. But now, when I query for any or multiple "strings", I will be getting ALL the languages back and the client will then have to display which one applies. With large strings and many languages, this feels like a lot of overhead.

My question then is, what is the best way to structure data in a case like this so that the strings and the likeCounts are fast and efficient?

If it helps and you want to go above and beyond with an answer/example, I will want a "user" object to reference all liked strings, but I will NOT require that a "string" also reference the users that have liked it.

EDIT:

One other case I could consider is doing manual join requests in the client. If I used the architecture in option 1 above to easily get the localized text, I could add an additional top-level object like:

```
{
  en: {
    strings: {
      0: "String 0 in English",
      1: "String 1 in English",
      ...
    }
  },
  es: {
    strings: {
      0: "String 0 in Spanish",
      1: "String 1 in Spanish",
      ...
    }
  },
  likes: {
    0: 110,
    1: 13,
    ...
  }
}
```

Then when in the client I could make two simultaneous requests and merge/join the results. Does this approach sound reasonable for Firebase? I do not think the overhead or latency would really suffer here.